# Why are both of the sentences correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

> Some questions in the exam were very easy.

> Some of the questions in the exam were very easy.

> Most students in our class are very nice.

> Most of the students in our class are very nice.

The question is why we can use both forms "in general way" and "in definite way". Linked question doesn't explain this case. It explains usage of "all" qualifier. We can use "All of the + noun" and "All the + noun", but this is another case.

Comment: It feels like there's a very slight difference between specificity or audience between the two. Using "of the" makes it seem more personal and specific.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference what "qualifier" is involved *(**some, all, a few, many, most,...**)* - it means the same regardless of whether you include ***of the*** before the relevant noun *(**questions, students**)*. It's mainly just a stylistic choice how you phrase it.